# Integration Testing with MongoDB - Authentication

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a module that uses mongodb and I'm writing an integration test for it.  I'm basing my test off the example [here](http://blogs.skicelab.com/maurizio/python-unit-testing-and-mongodb.html).

The error I'm seeing is `OperationFailure: command SON([('listDatabases', 1)]) failed: need to login`  when I call `conn.database_names()`

The problem is I'm not sure how to login.  I have tried adding --username and --password arguments to subprocess.Popen, with no luck, and the pymongo.Connection object doesn't have an authenticate method, although a pymongo database object does.

Is there a way I can either authenticate when I launch mongo from Popen, or restructure this so I have access to a database object?

```
class MongoTemporaryInstance(object):

    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = cls()
            atexit.register(cls._instance.shutdown)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        self._tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        self._process = subprocess.Popen(['mongod', '--bind_ip', 'localhost',
                                      '--port', str(MONGODB_TEST_PORT),
                                      '--dbpath', self._tmpdir,
                                      '--nojournal', '--nohttpinterface',
                                      '--noauth', '--smallfiles',
                                      '--syncdelay', '0',
                                      '--maxConns', '10',
                                      '--nssize', '1', ],
                                         stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'),
                                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            try:
                self._conn = pymongo.Connection('localhost', MONGODB_TEST_PORT)
            except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Does `pymongo.Connection('mongodb://<username>:<password>@localhost', MONGODB_TEST_PORT)` work? [pymongo.Connection](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html) seems to accept [mongodb URIs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) (according to the API).

Comment: There is nothing in the command line that should be requiring authentication.  In fact the --noauth does the opposite.  

Have you verified that there is no old monogd process left running that is using authentication on 'MONGODB_TEST_PORT'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as @RobMoore had suggested - there was an old mongodb process running using authentication on that port.  I changed the port and it worked!